# Subclassing UISlider to customize thumb image using IBDesignable/IBInspectable?

Tags: ios, swift, uislider, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I'm using this code [from](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86yf34Y24Uc) to customize my UISlider's thumbImage.  It builds correctly in the storyboard but when I build and run it does not show my image? Could it be because I have it hooked up as an outlet as well? (necessary because I need to set the slider's value in code)

```
@IBDesignable
class DesignableSlider: UISlider {



    @IBInspectable var thumbImage: UIImage? {
        didSet{
              setThumbImage(thumbImage, for: .normal)
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Works fine for me in a quick test - including having it hooked up to an `@IBOutlet`. Try it in a fresh project, and see if you get the same results. Since you say it's *"hooked up as an outlet"* are you possibly doing something in code that is changing it?

Comment: You could try using `get` and `set` instead of `didSet`.

Comment: @DonMag not doing anything other than setting the slider's value.